# Get data from share point site

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint

I have more than one of `share point sites` which are fully developed by `share point` technology. it is related data is stored in `share point DB`. 
My question is:  Is there  a way to get data from `share point` list site and store it in a `different DB`?
or how to get data from `share point page` and store it in a `DB`?

Comment: You can read sharepoint data such as Site,Subsite,list/library and item of list and then create it into new server.

Comment: There are lots of ways to "get data from `share point page` and ..", depending upon what each of those words mean. Touching the SP database directly is a big no-no, but there are several different Object/Access Models (SPOM, SPCOM, WebDAV, etc.) exposed depending on what needs to be done - from *where* and for *what `share point` data*?

Answer (score 0):

CAML Queries are most commonly used  for easily accessing  data inside SharePoint.

SharePoint object model provides many useful Classes which use CAML queries for fetching the data you need (listed below). These classes are fine tuned for specific scenarios.

```
SPQuery
ContentIterator
SPSiteDataQuery
PortalSiteMapProvider
CrossListQueryCache and CrossListQueryInfo
```

for more details check the following link:

http://extreme-sharepoint.com/2012/07/17/data-access-via-caml-queries/